# How to get request context user name

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

In My application, I have set below line to set `windows` authentication.

Executing the site using visual studio.

```
   `<authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>`
```

When i try to get context user name using
          `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" then, it gives me
empty value only.

Please guide me, i expect it to return - windows login as authentication is windows.

Please guide.

Comment: why down vote.. Its facing issue. please let me know if any detail require.

Comment: System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName;
        System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.Password;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had the same issue, do you have an authorization section in your web.config? Denying all the anonymous users fixed it for me.

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
```

Also I wouldn't access the user via HttpContext instead do it like this:

```
string username = User.Identity.Name;
```

Check also that you have enabled Windows Authentication on your web server, shouldn't be a problem for you because you are running the site with the IIS Express in Visual Studio most likely.

Comment: I added. now, its fine. But, problem is, when i hosted site on Iis THEN, Its now working. please guide me.

Comment: As already mentioned you have to enable Windows Authentification on your IIS. Check this guide by [microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) for that. I hope that helps.